# Laravel - sum of current user

Tags: mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I have a question ! How can i count sum of time of current user? I made simple todo app which request name and time. Each user has it's own tasks and under list of task i want to count sum not all todos from database but only from each user.

```
  $sum = DB::table('todos')
                ->where( ??? - there should be id of current logged in user)
                ->sum('time');
```

Comment: $todos = $request->user()->todo()->get();

Comment: and in database where todos are stored there's user_id where system automatically assign user_id based on request posted above

Comment: but it should read time from table todos and sum only user_id times current logged in

Comment: so for example when my user_id is 1 i should have sum of time tasks made by user_id 1. If user_id 2 i should have sum of time tasks made by user_id 2. etc etc

Comment: my bad: `DB::table('todos')->where('user', $user)->sum('times');` would probably work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you;

```
$sum = DB::table('todos')
            ->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->sum('time');
```

the `\Auth::user()->id` selects the ID of the user that is logged in currently.

Comment: not working ;( Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$id in header i have : use Auth;

Comment: Change auth() to \Auth::user()

Comment: Working Robin ! Thank u !