# Total Leave Taken - How to update total leave taken in a leave_balances table for a specific user

Tags: laravel-8

I created a method called getSumOfLeaveTaken() in a Leave Models in order  to sum the number of days taken for a leave for a specific user shown in a Leave Model below and call this methods in my controller to save the sum of leave taken in a leave_balances table. My leave_balance table is meant to save the sum of leave taken per leave_category and specific user. When I apply for a leave for 2 days the 2 days leaves was saved in leave_balance table and then later on I apply for another 3 days leave and the total_leave_taken is updated and summed up to 5 total_leave_taken

[image: leave taken]

[image: The sum of leave taken in leave_balances table]

If another user apply for 2 days leave the total_leave_taken for that user is 7 days.

[image: another user leave taken]

[image: total leave taken for another user id 2]

I stuck on how to make this correct as 2 days leaves becomes 7 days total leave taken. Please can anyone help

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;
    use App\Models\Leave;
    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Leave extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;

        protected $table = 'leaves';

        protected $fillable = [

                    'created_by', 
                    'leave_category_id',
                    'start_date', 
                    'end_date',
                    'num_days', 
                    'reason',
                    'publication_status',
                    'deletion_status',
        ];

        public static function getSumOfLeaveTaken(){
            
            $leavebalance = Leave::where('leave_category_id',1)->where('created_by',$userId = Auth::user()->id)->first()->sum('num_days');

            return $leavebalance;
        }



      }
```

My store methode

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $sdates = date("D", strtotime($request->start_date));
    $edates = date("D", strtotime($request->end_date));
    
    $leave_application = $this->validate($request, [
        'leave_category_id' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    $start_date = Carbon::parse(request('start_date'));
    $end_date = Carbon::parse(request('end_date'));

    $days = $start_date->diffInWeekdays($end_date);

    $weekly_holidays = WorkingDay::where('working_status', 0)
        ->get(['day'])
        ->toArray();

        if($weekly_holidays != null){

            foreach ($weekly_holidays as $weekly_holiday) {
                if ($sdates == $weekly_holiday['day'] || $edates == $weekly_holiday['day']) {
                    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
                }               
               }                
        }

        $monthly_holidays = Holiday::where('holiday_date', '=', $request->start_date)
        ->first(['holiday_date']);
        
        
   if($monthly_holidays == null){
    
    $result = Leave::create($leave_application +['num_days' => $days] +['reason' =>request('reason')] + ['created_by' => auth()->user()->id]);
    
  
    $rds = LeaveBalance::where('leave_category_id',$request->leave_category_id)->where('created_by',$userId = Auth::user()->id)->first();
    
    if(!isset($rds)){

    $carbon = Carbon::now();
    $nowInTarawa = Carbon::now('Pacific/Tarawa');
    $year = $nowInTarawa->format('Y');
    $yearIntvalue = intval($year);
    $leave_balance = new LeaveBalance();
    $leave_balance->leave_category_id = $request->leave_category_id;
    $leave_balance->created_by = $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $leave_balance->year = $yearIntvalue;
    $leave_balance->total_leave_taken = $leaves = Leave::getSumOfLeaveTaken($request->leave_category_id);
    $leave_balance->save();

}else

    {
        $leaves = Leave::getSumOfLeaveTaken($request->leave_category_id);
        LeaveBalance::where('created_by', $userId)->where('leave_category_id',$request->leave_category_id)
        ->update(['total_leave_taken' => $leaves]);

    }

    $inserted_id = $result->id;

    if (!empty($inserted_id)) {
        return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('message', 'Add successfully.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'Operation failed !');

   }

   
   if($monthly_holidays != null){
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
The link that help me solving this is found here [Laravel - sum of current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124663/laravel-sum-of-current-user)

I just change my getSumOfLeaveTaken() logic to and able to sum leave taken for a specific user.

```
    public static function getNumOfLeaveTaken($leave_category_id){
            
             $leavebalance  = DB::table('leaves')
            ->where('created_by', \Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('leave_category_id', $leave_category_id)
            ->sum('num_days');


            return $leavebalance;
        }
```